# ByteBuffer and converting between decimal and hex

Tags: java, int, byte, bytebuffer

What I want to do is take a decimal integer, convert it into hexadecimal, and then separate the bytes.

It's my understanding that `ByteBuffer` is the best way to do this. The integer will not exceed 65535, so the hex number is guaranteed to be 2 bytes. For an example, I have an integer of 40000 (hex value 9C40).

```
int n1 = 40000;
ByteBuffer b = ByteBuffer.allocate(2);
b.putInt(n1);
```

However, I get the following error when I run the program:

> Exception in thread "main" java.nio.BufferOverflowException

What am I doing wrong? Shouldn't 9C40 be written into `b` (with `b[0]` = 9C and `b[1]` = 40)?

Also, once I get past this, if I want to convert the value stored in `b[0]` (which is 9C) to decimal (which is 156), would I just use the following code?

```
int n2 = b.get(0);
```

Comment: I think the document says very clear putInt requires 4 bytes. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#putInt(int)

Comment: There is no hex conversion in your code, and `ByteBuffer` is not a solution for hex-encoding. Unclear what you're  asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are working with a ByteBuffer, it stores an amount of x allocated bytes. Now you allocated 2 bytes and you try to store a datatype that has the size of 4 bytes. So the buffer will run out of bounds as the message said. If you want to store this data in a two byte sized buffer, you either use a short (16 bit - 2 bytes) or you allocate 4 bytes for your ByteBuffer.

With short:

```
ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(2);
short myShort = (short) 40000;
bb.putShort(myShort);
System.out.println(String.format("%02X, %02X", bb.get(0), bb.get(1)));
```

With int:

```
ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(4);
int myInt = 40000;
bb.putInt(myInt);
System.out.println(String.format("%02X, %02X", bb.get(2), bb.get(3)));
```

Output: 9C, 40

Comment: I have a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46997683/sending-byte-array-of-approx-fixed-size-everytime) in which I am using Byte Buffer and I am confusing on how can I limit the size of byte array before sending to some other method. Wanted to see if you can help out.

Answer (score 1):

The data type you used to store the number `40000` is `int`, which requires 4 bytes of space. Yes I know the number won't exceed 65535 but the computer doesn't. You have to change it to an appropriate data type that can be stored in 2 bytes.

That data type, is `short`.

But there's another problem if you used `short`, you can't really store `40000` in `short` in Java is *signed*, so its max value is 32767.

So to store your `40000`, you have to store `-25536` instead in a `short`, because of overflow.

```
short n1 = (short)40000; // this will cause n1 to store -25536
ByteBuffer b = ByteBuffer.allocate(2);
b.putShort(n1);
```

Now it's time to print out the bytes. Bytes in Java are signed as well. So if you print this:

```
System.out.println(b.get(0));
System.out.println(b.get(1));
```

You'd get

```
-100
64
```

64 is expected since 64 in hex is 40, but why -100? Since bytes are signed, 156 can't be represented as 156. 156 in a signed byte is -100.

Comment: I have a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46997683/sending-byte-array-of-approx-fixed-size-everytime) here in which I am using Byte Buffer and I am confusing on how can I limit the size of byte array before sending to some other method. Wanted to see if you can help out.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of ByteBuffer I prefer Integer class which can convert the integer value to hex string & you can get each byte by index of method.

Use following code it do that
int n = 4000;
String hex = Integer.toHexString(n);

In this way you can get the hex value of any integer for one one byte use indexOf() method of string clas

You can get return the hex value as integer using valueOf() method in Integer class which takes two arguments one is string and another is radix